# What passes through serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

A dumb question, but still:

In C#, when I pass an object from one machine to another - what is available at the destination side?

Only public members? Properties? Methods? What else?

Comment: There is of course no reason to serialize methods

Comment: What kind of serialization? There's more than one kind. How are you passing objects from one machine to another? There's more than one way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the serialization method. The `BinaryFormatter` takes everything (that is `ISerializable`), the `XmlSerialzer` only public properties and fields with a setter (by default).

Comment: public properties - you mean their current state or actually the property itself? Meaning if the Property does additional logic will it be invoked on the destination upon calling?

Comment: The XmlDeserialzer will call the setter of the object and perform any logic specified.

Comment: @Elad serialization is taking *data* only; by default, `BinaryFormatter` takes the *fields*. To take the *logic* is "remoting"

Comment: @MarcGravell you disagree with Magnus ?

Comment: @Elad there is no way of answering that unless you tell us *very clearly* what serialization method you are using. The side-effects vary between each; `XmlSerializer` will indeed run setters for properties, but that isn't necessarily even the same *type* as the original (since it is contract based). `BinaryFormatter` touches fields; `DataContractSerializer` bypasses constructors (`XmlSerializer` executes constructors). Some other serializers can optionally behave like any of the inbuilt ones.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to realize is that the type definition of the object being deserialized must be available at the destination.

**Serialization only generates *data***. Either all or partial. The deserialization process constructs an object according to the type definition at the receiving end populates it according to deserialization data.

It would be worth your while to experiment with deserializing a type that is not defined or has a different definition at receiving end.